# Issue while setting virtual host with node.js on express

Tags: linux, node.js, express

I am building an application on node.js using Express. My application is running on port 3001. I want to set virtual host for my application so that when I use http://local.com:3001, it should lead me to my application's home page.

My node version is : `v0.12.3`
Express version : `4.12.4`
NPM version : `2.9.1`

I have added the host in /etc/hosts.
My application is at /var/www/local. I set up an express app under /var/www/vhost to act as vhost manager.After a lot of research, I tried using below two methods but none of them worked:

1) app.js of /var/www/vhost

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var vhost = require('vhost');
var app = express();
var main = express();

if (!module.parent) main.use(logger('dev'));

main.get('/', function(req, res){
res.send('Hello from main app!');
});

main.get('/:sub', function(req, res){
res.send('requested ' + req.params.sub);
});

// Redirect app

var redirect = express();

redirect.use(function(req, res){
if (!module.parent) console.log(req.vhost);
res.redirect('http://local.com:3001/' + req.vhost[0]);
});

// Vhost app

var app = module.exports = express();

app.use(vhost('*.local.com', redirect)); // Serves all subdomains via      Redirect app
app.use(vhost('local.com', main)); // Serves top level domain via Main server app

if (!module.parent) {
app.listen(3001);
console.log('Express started on port 3001');
}
```

2)  app.js of /var/www/vhost using express-vhost

```
var evh = require('express-vhost'),
express = require('express');

var appFactory = function(echo) {
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
var err = new Error('Not Found');
err.status = 404;
next(err);
});

// error handlers

 // development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
 app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: err
  });
});
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
 res.status(err.status || 500);
 res.render('error', {
  message: err.message,
  error: {}
});
});


module.exports = app;
return app;

};

var server = express();
server.use(evh.vhost(server.enabled('trust proxy')));
server.listen(3006);

evh.register('http://local.com:3001', appFactory('/var/www/local/app.js'));
```

Any suggestions if I am doing something wrong here or is there any other way to achieve the concept of virtual hosting with express on node.js would be really helpful. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I have also same issue. Thanks to ask here.